# Replace column values using mask and multiple mappings

Tags: python, pandas, mapping, mask

I have two dataframes. One is v_df and looks like this:

| VENDOR_ID | VENDOR_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | APPLE |
| 456 | GOOGLE |
| 987 | FACEBOOK |

The other is n_df and looks like this:

| Vendor_Name | GL_Transaction_Description |
| --- | --- |
| AMEX | HELLO 345 |
| Not assigned | BYE 456 |
| Not assigned | THANKS 123 |

I want to populate the 'Vendor_Name' column in n_df on the condition that the 'GL_Transaction_Description' on the same row contains any VENDOR_ID value from v_df. So the resulting n_df would be this:

| Vendor_Name | GL_Transaction_Description |
| --- | --- |
| AMEX | HELLO 345 |
| GOOGLE | BYE 456 |
| APPLE | THANKS 123 |

So far I have written this code:

```
v_list = v_df['VENDOR_ID'].to_list()
mask_id = list(map((lambda x: any([(y in x) for y in v_list])), n_df['GL_Transaction_Description']))

n_df['Vendor_Name'].mask((mask_id), other = 'Solution Here', inplace=True)
```

I am just not able to grasp what to write in the 'other' condition of the final masking. Any ideas? (n_df has more than 100k rows, so the execution speed of the solution is of high importance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `Series.str.extract` + `map`

```
i = v_df['VENDOR_ID'].astype(str)
m = v_df.set_index(i)['VENDOR_NAME']
s = n_df['GL_Transaction_Description'].str.extract(r'(\d+)', expand=False)

n_df['Vendor_Name'].update(s.map(m))
```

#### Explanations

Create a mapping series `m` from the `v_df` dataframe by setting the `VENDOR_ID` column as the index and selecting the `VENDOR_NAME` column

```
>>> m

VENDOR_ID
123       APPLE
456      GOOGLE
987    FACEBOOK
Name: VENDOR_NAME, dtype: object
```

Now `extract` the vendor id from the strings in `GL_Transaction_Description` column

```
>>> s

0    345
1    456
2    123
Name: GL_Transaction_Description, dtype: object
```

`Map` the extracted vendor id with the mapping series `m` and `update` the mapped values in `Vendor_Name` column

```
>>> n_df

  Vendor_Name GL_Transaction_Description
0        AMEX                  HELLO 345
1      GOOGLE                    BYE 456
2       APPLE                 THANKS 123
```

Comment: Good solution and nice explanation, but it is quite slow in my case (n_df has more than 100k rows)

Comment: @JohnMantios Thanks for testing the solution and yes `replacement` with regex pattern will take some time for `100K` rows. I will see if i can come up with anything more performant..As an alternative you can try str extract but again i believe that will also take more or less the same time..

Comment: @JohnMantios I've edited the answer..See if you get any performance improvements.

Comment: It throws the following error in the last line: 'Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects'

Comment: Thats because your `VENDOR_ID` column contains duplicate entries. First we need to drop the duplicate vendor ids.. Please check `m = v_df.drop_duplicates('VENDOR_ID').astype({'VENDOR_ID': 'str'}).set_index('VENDOR_ID')['VENDOR_NAME']`

Comment: It runs without errors but nothing changes in the target column. Everything remains the same

Comment: @JohnMantios Lets discuss [`here`](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228691/ds5)